# Как подставить значение переменной в DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#region').change(function(){
    var selectRegion = $(this).val();
    $('.shop-item-box[region="selectRegion"]').fadeOut();
});
```

Есть такой код. Как selectRegion подставлять в атрибут из `$('.shop-item-box[region="ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ"]')`

Comment: `" + var + "`  вроде бы так

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#region').change(function(){
    var selectRegion = $(this).val();
    $('.shop-item-box[region="' + selectRegion + '"]').fadeOut();
});
```